# Angular Jasmine - Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' error in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am writing test cases in Angular using Jasmine 3.6.0 and typescript 4.1.5 with "strict": false in tsconfig.json file

I wanted to spyOn component method called 'close' and as per syntax I wrote below code

```
let spy = spyOn<MyComponent>(component,'close');
```

It was working fine but after copying source code to different folder I installed node modules and it started giving below error

**'Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never''**

I know this question is asked many times and I tried those solutions but I am facing same error.
I don't understand what is the actual problem as my strict mode is also off.

Comment: Try removing the `<MyComponent>`.

Comment: spyOn<MyComponent, any> will solve it, because it changes the type never to any and accepts string

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
let spy = spyOn<MyComponent, any>(component,'close')
```

Comment: Please explain your code and how it resolves the question asked.

Comment: most likely because 'close' is a private method, public methods don't need this.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved problem

```
let spy = spyOn<MyComponent>(component,'close' as never)
```

As of now its working and not giving any errors but I don't know that is correct or not

Answer (score -2):

I encountered it now, and it happened because the method I am trying to spyOn() is with private accessibility.

You have to change it to public to be able to unit test and skip this error.

Comment: you shouldn't change a method to public just to be able to test it. That would mean you should neve have private methods, because you want all your code to be covered by tests, right? You should find different ways to test private methods, like, for example, test the thing resulted from the call to the private method.

Comment: first part is correct. the code should not be changed to be testable. 

although sometimes during testing I find parts that might need refactoring. but thats more a result of the a different approach to the code when testing.

the second part is sometimes not achievable, because you need to mock responses from private functions. I too did not find a good solution to that kind of problem though.